# CYK build parsing tree from table

Tags: parsing, chomsky-normal-form, cyk

How do I build a parsing tree after I obtain the CYK table? I didn't understand what Wikipedia was trying to say.
Example:

```
A
-      C
A      -      B
B,D    C,F    E     B,D
```

How do I return a list of rules applied to get from A to BCED (or any other combination of letters from the longest line of the table)?